# What is the best way to change citation color? I want it to change from blue to black

Tags: citing

```
\usepackage[
    colorlinks=true
    ,breaklinks
    ,%ngerman
    ]{hyperref} % needed for creating hyperlinks in the document, the option colorlinks=true gets rid of the awful boxes, breaklinks breaks lonkg links (list of figures), and ngerman sets everything for german as default hyperlinks language
\usepackage[hyphenbreaks]{breakurl} % benÃ¶tigt fÃŒr das Brechen von URLs in Literaturreferenzen, hyphenbreaks auch bei links, die ÃŒber eine Seite gehen (mit hyphenation).
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{c1}{rgb}{0,0,1} % blue
\definecolor{c2}{rgb}{0.1,0.1,0.1} % light blue
\definecolor{c3}{rgb}{0.3,0,0.9} % red blue
\hypersetup{
    linkcolor= {c1}, % internal links
    citecolor={c2}, % citations
    urlcolor={c3} % external links/urls
}
```

Comment: add `urlcolor=black` to the options

Comment: thanks for your help, but it didn't help. My citation numbering, table of contents are blue in color.  I want to make it black.