# Change citations color to blue

Tags: biblatex, hyperref

I've been trying to follow the other SO questions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238098/how-to-change-reference-color-to-blue) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402660/what-is-the-best-way-to-change-citation-color-i-want-it-to-change-from-blue-to) but nothing works for some reason.
I'm new to LaTex and trying to change the color of the citations from black to blue.

Currently each citation is a number: `[1]` with a `hyperref`, so when I click on it it moves me to the last page.

I'm currently using the following packages for citations:

```
\usepackage {hyperref}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}
```

And writing each citation as `\cite{*}`

I tried using this package `\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}` but it doesn't seem to do anything

I'm not sure what other code to add here as I'm new in this community, but let me know if there's anything else I should add.

Comment: Note that `hyperref` should generally be the last package you load in the preamble.

Comment: Anyway, we'll need to see a small yet compilable example document that shows what you are doing at the moment with as little excess code as possible (a so-called MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864). I just tried https://gist.github.com/moewew/8f737f16d89101874a087ef10a72795a and the citation numbers are blue as expected. If you are using a template or heavily customised document class it is very possible that it applies additional hyperref options (behind the scenes) that counter your document settings.

Comment: Ah that was silly of me and a really easy fix. I moved `hyperref` to be the last package as you said and everything works! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `hyperref` should generally be the last package you load (there are a few documented exceptions like `cleveref`, which should be loaded after `hyperref`).

In the following example the citations are blue as expected

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Blue citation number 1]

At least in this example things still work fine if you load `hyperref` before `biblatex`, so there must be something else going on in your actual document. But since it was discussed in the comments that loading `hyperref` last helped, I thought I'd still post an answer.